# Is it possible to render GLSL over video?

Tags: rendering, video, glsl

I've never worked with Blender, but was asking around about finding a way to render GLSL over video and a friend - who knew that the two could both be done in Blender, but not whether they could be done in concert - suggested that I give it a look. I'm sufficiently competent with GLSL to be dangerous, but have never worked with Blender. I'm sure I can work out the details of the video editor, but I want to take a huge collection of telemetry data that I collect while shooting video, and render misc visualizations over the video frames.

I can transpose the telemetry into any format that will work for Blender to be able to apply the correct data to each frame of video. I just need to know if it's possible, and possible have someone point in the direction of some examples.

Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the key word **Huge**, you might want to implement your own GLSL and video processing pipeline from scratch rather than using Blender.

Comment: Huge and Blender don't go well together... It's certainly possible, but you should start with one clip and see if it plays back in realtime. You can store clips in RAM, but only until your RAM runs out, also not on the fly.